# API Jive get categories error : Uncaught Passed URI does not match "/places/{uri}": /api/core/v3/places/

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, jive

i use Jive and i want to get all categories and for each category, i want to create a checkbox for each of them.
Currently, i have my array with all categories, but when i try to create checkbox, it return me this error :
" Uncaught Passed URI does not match "/places/{uri}": /api/core/v3/places/ "
Someone can help me ?

```js
///////////////// function checkbox for each category ////////////////

$("#submit_a_question").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modal").addClass('is-show');
        $("#ideasContainer").height((height + 100) + "px");
        resizeIframe();

        fieldsPlaceholder(appLang);
  var categoriesToShow = categories(placeID);
  var container = $('#listCheckboxCategories');
  var listCheckboxCategories = $('#listCheckboxCategories');
  var CheckboxCreate = $('input />', {type: 'checkbox'});
 if(tileConfig.isThereFilterRadios == "Yes"){
   $('#ShowCategories').show();
   $('#listDropdownCategories').show();
   $.each(categoriesToShow.res, function(index, value) {

    CheckboxCreate.appendTo(container); 
   });
 } 
  
  
  ///////// function to get all categories in an array /////////
  
   function categories(placeID){
 var request = osapi.jive.corev3.places.get({
 uri : '/api/core/v3/places/' + placeID 
 });
 // var res = [];
  
 request.execute(function(response) {
  if (typeof response.error != 'undefined') {
   console.log("API call failed");
  } else {
   console.log(response);
   response.getCategories().execute(
    function (res){ 
     console.log("cat",res);
    }); 
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: Your "placeID" seems to be null/void. Where are you getting this from? Thanks.

Comment: the placeID is not null, i get the value in the configuration part : if(tileConfig.data.place_id !== undefined){
        $('#tile_file_place_id').val(tileConfig.data.place_id)

Comment: You can change the place URI to "/places/{placeId}" instead of "/api/core/v3/places/{placeId}" and see if that helps? Also from a tile you should be able to get the place object that contains that tile with "jive.tile.getContainer()".

Comment: sadly, it return the same error, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute the call successfully by using "/places/{placeId}" in the URI as below:

```
osapi.jive.corev3.places.get({uri: '/places/1003'}).execute(function(response) { 
    console.log(response); 
});
```

For which I have received the place object in the response, as expected:

```
{ type: "space", 
  parent: "http://localhost:8080/api/core/v3/places/1000", 
  placeTopics: Array(0), 
  displayName: "water-cooler", 
  iconCss: "jive-icon-space", …}
```

Are you sure your "placeId" has the correct value? Maybe log the URI you are sending before making the call and check if the format matches the one I have mentioned above. Thanks.